# Dynamic tailwind class not correctly rendering in production

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, astrojs

In my application I created a Stepper Menu component

[image: stepper component]

In order to make it visually active when clicking on a step, I compare the url with Astro.url and return a boolean active in my component

```
---
import Step from "./Step.astro";

interface Props {
  steps: Array<Record<string, string>>;
  slug: string;
}

const { steps, slug } = Astro.props as Props;
// variables for checking url
const pathname = new URL(Astro.request.url).pathname.split("/");
const lastUrlElem = pathname.pop();
---

<section aria-labelledby="timeline-title" class="lg:col-span-1 lg:col-start-3">
  <div class="px-4 py-5 shadow sm:rounded-lg sm:px-6">
    <div class="mt-2 flow-root">
      <ul role="list" class="-mb-8">
        <Step
          first={true}
          <!-- active props boolean --!>
          active={slug === lastUrlElem} 
          last={false}
          title="Intro"
          link={`/cours/${slug}`}
        />
        {
          steps.map((step, index) => {
            return (
              <Step
                first={false}
                <!-- active props boolean --!>
                active={Object.values(step)[0] === lastUrlElem}
                step={index + 1}
                last={index == steps.length - 1}
                title={Object.keys(step)}
                link={`/cours/${slug}/${Object.values(step)}`}
              />
            );
          })
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

After checking locally and then in preproduction, my active boolean goes from true to false and the pathname and lastUrlElem variables work

However in production nothing is happening visually while locally everything is working correctly, do you have any ideas?

Is this from tailwind? (I tried passing a class:list without success)

Step component with tailwind styles :

```
<span class={`h-8 w-8 rounded-full flex items-center justify-center ring-white ${
            active ? "bg-green-500" : "bg-gray-400"
          }`}
>
...
</span>
```

Comment: For `pathname` you can use `Astro.url.pathname` instead of creating your own URL

Comment: It may be an issue where the pathname has a trailing slash in certain circumstances. For example if pathname is `foo/` and slugs is `foo`, the `slug === lastUrlElem` check will be false.

Comment: @BryceRussell I have tried with Astro.url.pathname same result work locally but not after build

Comment: You can try something like this `const slugs = Astro.url.pathname.replace(/\/$/, '').split('/')`, this will cover any case of a tailing slash in the pathname

Comment: @BryceRussell omg special thanks, it works correctly but why do you think it creates a difference in preprod compared to when I'm on localhost:3000?

Comment: It depends on your host, some hosts force a trailing slash and some don't, you can configure the trailing slash behavior of the dev server to match prod using this option: [`trailingSlash`](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/configuration-reference/#trailingslash)